# iOS Development UI standards

Tags: ios, uielement

I have read the following iOS standards like navigation bar is 44ppt in height and tab bar is 49ppt in height. In my app the top navigation bar is 53ppt and the bottom tab bar is also 53 ppt, is it ok or do i need to set the heights as in standards.I have read those standards in the following link http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html. I just want to know whether it is allowed to increase the size of the standard navigation and tab bars. Thank you

Comment: yes you can use different sizes for tabbar and navigation bar

Comment: the _iOS interface Guideline_ usually defines the **minimum** size of each control, which is still confortable to use by an averagre human finger. therefore you can implement bigger controls without any fear (or even smaller too but that is just not recommended because there is risk they may not pass the review procedure – that is why the _Guideline_ defines the minimum sizes).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should read [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html). AFAIK Apple does not like GUI elements which are similar to standard but differ from them or work differently. Your app could be rejected when you will try to publish it in AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to change height of navigation bar

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customNav)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,70);
    return newSize;
}
@end
```

and for tabbar size you can use

```
#import 

@interface UITabBar (NewSize)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size;
@end

#import "UITabBar+NewSize.h"

@implementation UITabBar (NewSize)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width,44);
    return newSize;
}
@end
```

Comment: I am not using standard navigation bar. I have my own navigation view. But i want to know whether it is ok to have 53ppt height for that view.

Comment: What's the point in taking a `CGSize` for both `sizeThatFits:` methods when you don't use the `height` from the `CGSize`? they should really be something like `- (CGSize)sizeThatFitsWithWidth:(CGFloat)width { return CGSizeMake(width, 44); }`